# Is there a way to have a Windows shell script execute everything relative to its location rather than the location it was invoked from?

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file

I'm aware of %~dp0, which represents the fully expanded directory that contains the batch script, but what I'm looking for is either:

- a method to invoke the batch script from Perl in such a manner that allows me to use the batch script without modification and have all directories in it be in relation to the batch script location
- a single statement I can put in the batch script that is a flag to use the location of the batch script as the starting point for all directories

I'm currently invoking the batch script using this method in Perl:

```
`"../run.bat" -f $ARGV[$#ARGV]`;
```

and then capturing the output and doing processing to it.

Comment: I am not at all aware of %~dp0. Look horrible. What is it?

Comment: Manni: When used in a batch file it will contain the drive (`d`) and full path (`p`) of the zero-th argument (`0`), i. e. the currently executing program/batch. You can find more about this in `help for`. It's fairly standard batch file knowledge.

Comment: And people say Perl looks like line noise. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understand your question. But why don't you simply change the current directory in your perl script to the batch script's directory and then call the batch script?

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not even thinking of this...it's perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Use [pushd](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/pushd.mspx) and [popd](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/popd.mspx).  Add the line

```
@pushd %~dp0
```

to the beginning of the batch script.  This will change the working directory to the base directory of the batch file.  For the sake of completeness (and in case the batch file is going to be used by other batch files), you should add

```
@popd
```

at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bat script that starts a catalyst server perl script contained in the location relative to the .bat script:  MyPhp/script/

```
set bindir=%~dp0
set perlpath=%bindir%perl\bin
set buildpath=%bindir%\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;%perlpath%;%buildpath%
"%perlpath%\wperl.exe" "%bindir%MyPhp\script\myphp_server.pl" -p 35900
```

Here's a VBS script to start this same script without spawining a cmd window:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) &  fso.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) & "\perl shell.bat"& Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Really horrible stuff, but it works